# Compiler Warning 4456 using VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-warnings, boost-variant

If I compile the following small programm with Visual Studio 2015, 
I get the following compiler warning in line 9:

```
warning C4456: Declaration of "iter" shadows previous declaration
```

This is my small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    boost::variant<double, int> v{ 3.2 };
    if (auto iter = boost::get<int>(&v)) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
    else if( auto iter = boost::get<double>(&v)) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm curious if this is a compiler bug or a serious error.

**Revised**

As @Zeta found out, the following is legal C++ code, even I never imagined. The program will crash, due to using an undefined `iter`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    boost::variant<double, int> v{ 3.2 };
    if (auto iter = boost::get<int>(&v)) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
    else if( auto iter2 = boost::get<double>(&v)) {
        std::cout << *iter2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would it be a compiler bug?

Comment: @Zeta `{ iter = foo(); if(iter) { … } } else ...` would be a syntax error, so `iter` is in scope of the `else`.

Comment: @melpomene nvm missed the `else` before the second `if`.

Comment: I think @Zeta got the point. Just corrected the code a little bit. There is no warning, if I compile using Wandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS is correct. You have two `iter` at hand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    boost::variant<double, int> v{ 3.2 };
    if (auto iter = boost::get<int>(&v)) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
    else if( auto iter2 = boost::get<double>(&v)) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl; // whoops
    }
}
```

That's because

```
if(value = foo()) { 
    bar();
} else { 
    quux();
}
```

is the same as

```
{
    value = foo();

    if(value) { 
        bar();
    } else { 
        quux();
    }
}
```

Note that `value` is in scope for `else`. This includes any nested `if` within the (implicit) `else` block. You can look this up in C++11's [stmt.select] section, paragraph 3:

> … A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either
>   introduced by the type-specifier-seq or the declarator of the
>   condition) is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of
>   the substatements controlled by the condition. If the name is
>   re-declared in the outermost block of a substatement controlled by the
>   condition, the declaration that re-declares the name is ill-formed. [
>   Example:
>
> ```
> if (int x = f()) {
>     int x; // ill-formed, redeclaration of x
> }
> else {
>     int x; // ill-formed, redeclaration of x
> }
> ```

Comment: Wow. This is far from being obvious. Is this somewhere in the specs of C++?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf 6.4/3 [stmt.select]

Comment: It's less explicit in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf but I believe 6.3.3/4 [basic.scope.block] applies.

Comment: @Melpomene You don't need the new C++17-if-syntax to define variables inside 
an if-statement, that has been valid for ages…
`if(T * ptr = …) { /*code that uses ptr*/ }`
Is a classical pattern in pointer-heavy code...